# Multiple input box in inline form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use the solution provide by @dippas here 
[Inline form make input text full width and responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43654548/inline-form-make-input-text-full-width-and-responsive)
My new request is how to put multiple input text and fill all the space.

I am aware that we can not use width with inline form like mention in bootstrap website

> Requires custom widths Inputs, selects, and textareas are 100% wide by
>   default in Bootstrap. To use the inline form, you'll have to set a
>   width on the form controls used within. The default width of 100% as
>   all form elements gets when they got the class form-control didn't
>   apply if you use the form-inline class on your form.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
.form-inline {
  display: flex;
  padding:5px !important;
}

.flex {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex !important
}

.flex input {
  flex: 1 !important ;
  padding-right:15px !important;

}
.form-inline .form-group {
  padding-right:15px !important;
}

</style>
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4><b>Search Options</b></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <form class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button"
                  class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"
                  data-toggle="dropdown"
                  aria-haspopup="true"
                  aria-expanded="false"
                  >Account ID &nbsp; <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#" (click)="doAction('account_id')">Account ID</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" (click)="doAction('company_name')">Company Name</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" (click)="doAction('account_type')">Account Type</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" (click)="doAction('marketplaces')">Marketplaces</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="row" style="display: block">
          <div class="form-group flex" >
            <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" id="filter_id" placeholder="Put your filter here">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"> Fermer </button>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group flex">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" id="filter_id" placeholder="Put your filter here">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"> Fermer </button>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group flex">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" id="filter_id" placeholder="Put your filter here">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"> Fermer </button>
          </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add `display:flex` to `.row`, because now the parent of `.flex` is `.row`

```css
/* !important only for this snippet */

.form-inline {
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px !important;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 1
}

.flex {
  flex: 0 100%;
  display: flex !important
}

.flex input {
  flex: 1 !important;
  padding-right: 15px !important;
}

.form-inline .form-group {
  padding-right: 15px !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4><b>Search Options</b></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <form class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Account ID &nbsp; <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#" (click)="doAction('account_id')">Account ID</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" (click)="doAction('company_name')">Company Name</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" (click)="doAction('account_type')">Account Type</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" (click)="doAction('marketplaces')">Marketplaces</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group flex">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" id="filter_id" placeholder="Put your filter here">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"> Fermer </button>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group flex">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" id="filter_id" placeholder="Put your filter here">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"> Fermer </button>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group flex">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" id="filter_id" placeholder="Put your filter here">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"> Fermer </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I use it bu i want like in this code but each input text fill the space left in its row

Comment: Can I have the first input beside the dropdown button ? I know I am too begginer in css !

Comment: don't understand what you want

Comment: @dippas Yes you can do it but then you will have to wrap drop down and first input together

Comment: Hope that this image can illustrate my request . http://hpics.li/4de729d